# 'if False' statement in python

Tags: python

I saw some of python code from my colleague.

```
def sample_func():

   # doWork here
   doWork();
   # doWork failed
   if False: 
      ...
```

what does `if False` mean?

Comment: I think he didn't want that code block to execute, and put an `if False` statement to do so. This is not a good practise though.

Comment: well `if False` will never evaluate to True so it does nothing

Comment: That probably means he didn't need that code to run at any condition, but was unsure if he will need that code in future, so he put that code in an unreachable flow control (if) branch. If it is so, then it is a bad code style: version control must be done with version control systems, not with dead logic branches and commenting code.

Comment: In addition to the `if False:` statement being a sign of debugging code being left in a function that should have been removed altogether, the `;` semicolon is also bad style.

Comment: Also the fact I see a semicolon makes me think whoever wrote it does not write much python code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, `if False` is a way of preventing the code which follows from executing, but is bad practice.

So why is it bad practice?

The condition `if False` is executed at runtime, so there is a slight overhead compared to a comment.  One reason for using it might be that there are already triple quoted comments inside the block, so commenting might not work easily.

Most editors these days use a colour coding to indicate comments, however they are not smart enough to realise that the code is not executed.  So when reading the code it would not be obvious that the code is bypassed unless you spot the condition.   The very fact that you have had to come to this site to ask what this does illustrates the point!

The practice may have been inherited from a language like C or C++ where a similar *pre-processor* directive can be given, but this then prevents compilation in those languages (and is still horrible).  The presence of the trailing semi-colon might indicate the author's background in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

`if False:` means that the code under this condition will not run.

As this condition is always false, the code of this branch is not executed.

I think your colleague just did not want that code to run.
Note that it is quite an ugly way of bypassing this section and there are other ways to do this in a more appropriate way such as commenting (the most obvious one, and it is just a keyboard shortcut away in every editor).

Comment: I will be glad to hear about the downvotes if someone has a problem with me saying this is "ugly". I'd like to link to the PEP20 (python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020) and say that "Readability counts". If you never lost time because you were trying to understand or fix code for nothing, because a statement like this one was hundreds of lines above, then you are lucky but this is still bad practice.

Comment: Well I disagree I am answering the question by telling the OP that this code is used to bypass a section, prevent the code from running, although I made it clear that this was not the best way to do it.

Comment: **`what`** `does if False mean?` not **why**. Your answer is fine as a comment. not as answer.

Comment: I see what you mean although I think it is a bit fetched far. I've edited my answer to make it more clear about explaining what the code does. Thanks for taking the time to explain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That means it will never be executed. Probably this is temporary code to be filled in later or to temporarily not executed.

I would expect at least a TODO / comment why it will not be executed.